# context().parent() in a router pool

Tags: java, akka, router

I create a pool of actors like this:

```
 public ParentActor() {

    childRouter = getContext().actorOf(
        new SmallestMailboxPool(actorPoolSize)
            .props(Props.create(Child.class)),
        "ChildRouter");
  }
```

Then somewhere in the child actor I have the following:

```
if (message instanceof someMessage) {

    context().parent().tell(someOtherMessage, getSelf());
}
```

I was expecting that the `sometherMessage` will be received in the `ParentActor`; instead, this goes into an infinite loop. To debug this further I added some logs in the child actor as follows:

```
log.debug("who is my parent {} ",  context().parent().getPath())
```

This gives me the following path:

```
/ActorSystem/user/ParentActor/ChildRouter
```

Which makes me think that the parent of one of the actors in the pool is the router actor--is this the correct behavior? How should I send a message back to the actor that spawned the router actor? I am confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the router is the parent (or supervisor) of the routees. From the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/routing.html#supervision):

> Routees that are created by a pool router will be created as the router’s children. The router is therefore also the children’s supervisor.

When you make the following call in a routee...

```
context().parent().tell(someOtherMessage, getSelf());
```

...the `someOtherMessage` message is sent to the router.

The actor that you've named `ParentActor` is not the parent of the `Child` actors that are created as part of the `childRouter` pool. If you want a routee to send a message to `ParentActor`, one approach is to change the `Child` actor class to take an `ActorRef` as a constructor argument:

```
public class Child extends AbstractActor {
  private final ActorRef target;

  public Child(ActorRef target) {
    this.target = target;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Then in `ParentActor`, when creating the router, you can pass the reference to `ParentActor` (with `getSelf()`) to the `Props` for creating the routees:

```
childRouter = getContext().actorOf(
    new SmallestMailboxPool(actorPoolSize)
        .props(Props.create(Child.class, getSelf())),
    "ChildRouter");
```

Now the `Child` actors can send messages to `ParentActor`:

```
if (message instanceof someMessage) {
  target.tell(someOtherMessage, getSelf());
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation and the solution!